# trouble updating jQuery to more recent version

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

I am trying to update the jQuery version from 1.7 to a 1.11, but I am having trouble with the syntax for selecting elements on an html page with specific criteria. This syntax worked with 1.7, but appears to no longer be supported.

Here is what no longer works:

```
var arrdummy = jQuery(':input[name^="sx_"]:[name$="'+String(sx_no)+'"]:[name!="sx_date'+String(sx_no)+'"]');
```

The error I get is:

`Syntax Error, unrecognized expression :input[name^="sx_"]:[name$="01"]:[name!="sx_date01"]`

I have looked at http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#quot-input-quot-attr-quot-type-quot-newvalue-in-oldie , but I don't understand which of the updates might affect me.

Any help is much appreciated.

A secondary question: Version 1.7 worked fine for me, I did not encounter the problems that those later versions are attempting to fix. How important is it to update to the most recent version?

Thank you,
Beate

Comment: and what on earth should the colon mean in the selector?

Comment: `:[name$="` is wrong. No idea why that worked in 1.7. `:` isn't supposed to be there.

Comment: I misunderstood the syntax provided in the O'Reilly jQuery cookbook. I took all those colons out, and it worked! Thank you!